# Automatically truncate data when inserting

Tags: php, mysql, windows, pdo

My MySQL Server (running with PHP via PDO on Windows 2008 Server) returns error code 1406 (data too long for field) when inserting strings longer than allowed in a column. The thing is I read somewhere that what MySQL usually truncates the data when it is not in strict mode. I changed the sql_mode in my.ini so that even at startup it doesn't enter in strict mode (it is currently ""), but it is still giving me the error and rolls back, so the data is lost (truncating is the desired behaviour of the site).

I entered to the command line and made an insert with a long string in a shorter varchar field and it does truncate the data and save, but it is the site that doesn't. When I changed the mode back to strict, it didn't truncate in the command line (only the error).

Also, I made the site output the current sql mode, both global and session (@@GLOBAL.sql_mode and @@SESSION.sql_mode) and they both output "" but just don't work as desired.

Does anyone know what is causing this and/or how to change it?

My suspicion is that it may have to do with PDO enabled with PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, but I have read and can't find anything helpful about that (I don't really think this is definitely the explanation, but I am just putting this out there so that you know as much as possible about the problem).

Thank you very much

Comment: I doubt it's due to PDO, but there's a simple way to check: attempt to insert some excessively long data from the MySQL command line tool (or some other client)?  How are you obtaining the values of the `sql_mode` variables?

Comment: Ok, this might be a dumb question, but why would you want it to truncate your data and not tell you? It would seem to me that if it can not store your data it should report an error and stop, not blindly accept it and then throw part of it away, what if it is a XML or JSON that you can now no longer parse because you are missing the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not really do that - please don't let bad data into your database, and sanitize it in your scripts before you insert.

If you don't know actual width of your VARCHAR columns or don't want to hard-code it in your scripts, you can read it from database by querying [INFORMATION_SCHEMA table `COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html) using query like this:

```
SELECT
    column_name,
    data_type,
    character_maximum_length,
    ordinal_position
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'mytable'
```

(you may want to limit this to only `data_type = 'varchar'`).
Having this information and specifically `character_maximum_length`, you can use PHP [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to trim your input strings to desired length.

Advantage of this approach is that it does not alter any server configuration, and should work for any other databases, not only MySQL.

But if you insist on doing it unsafe way, you can try to temporarily disable strict mode by executing this:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

After that MySQL should silently trim strings. Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. The PHP part of the site is calling a MySQL Stored Procedure, so I can't trim in PHP, but I guess what I will do is a BEFORE INSERT trigger to trim the strings. `character_maximum_length` will still be useful because from installation to installation the database schema may be different, so it will keep it generic.

Comment: I generally agree with you that data shouldn't be truncated but as much as possible. In Sql Server, we can insert a larger data into columns and it will only throw a warning for this which since most applications have feed back loop (user immediately can see inserted data on their screen) it is not a major issue. but in MySQL you can't disable this without also disabling invalid data in date columns, key checking, rounded decimals, not allowing null in not null column, not allowing characters in numeric field and ... and I find this a really dumb design.

Comment: in [5.1.10 Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) page the only warning that is handled as error (and included in `ER_*`), is `WARN_DATA_TRUNCATED` (near end of page)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the mysql server is in "not forgiving" mode, aka. traditional (most times). What you read is true, if mysql server operates in forgiving mode. If you are trying to insert too long string, it can be really important information, therefore mysql will issue a error. You have a few alternatives:

1: Use insert ignore (which will transform all errors into warnings and will proceed to truncating the data)

2: For the current session, set the sql_mode to ''

With either of these your problem should go away.

PS: I have read the error you are getting, but i still think the server is operating in traditional mode (so it's no mistake that i recommended sql_mode set to empty).

PS2: After changing the my.cnf, did you restart the mysql server?